# Jquery/JS malfunction when window is not visible

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using JS to make a simple function that displays 3 items one at a time. Works well when you're looking at the page, but when you minimize or change tabs then return, all three items are shown.

Anyone know why? It's as if fadeIn(x) keeps running but hide() stops working. I even checked with different classes.

Here is the code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

function start() {
  $(".featured-items").hide();
  $( ".item-1" ).fadeIn('slow');
  setTimeout(one, 5000);
}
  function one() {
  $(".featured-items").hide();
  $( ".item-2" ).fadeIn('slow');
  setTimeout(two, 5000);
}
function two() {
  $(".featured-items").hide();
  $( ".item-0" ).fadeIn('slow');
  setTimeout(start, 5000);
}
setTimeout(start, 5000);

});
```

Problem solved, check the best answer below and make sure to read comments to get a good understanding. Thanks to all

Comment: Have one function, use a modulo 3 counter.

Comment: The animations queue up and don't run until the tab has focus.  If you used the callback of .fadeIn, this likely wouldn't happen (the loop would in effect be paused until you return.)

Comment: How come fadeIn works but hide queus up like you said?

Comment: Are you sure hide is queuing up? rather than being undone once fadeIn happens when you refocus?

Comment: Ah yes you are right. Passing queu: false to fadeIn solves the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Updated to provide complete answer)

Your original code is too complex, and a more flexible and simpler implementation is to have just one function, and an array of items in the gallery. Secondly, you should modify your code so the `fadeIn` animation starts immediately instead of getting queued. Having only one function instead of several makes alterations such as this easier.

Note that in the code below, as in your original code, the various gallery items are classes rather than single element ids and could fade in multiple items.

```
var gallery = [ '.item-1', '.item-2', '.item-3' ];
var i = 0;
function galleryEvent() {
    $(".featured-items").hide();
    $( gallery[i] ).fadeIn({duration: 'slow', queue: false});

    i = (i + 1) % gallery.length;
    setTimeout(galleryEvent, 5000);
}

// start everything off....
galleryEvent();
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution. Just for educational purposes, though, do you know why that problem happens with the original? I'll still use your solution, that goes without saying.

Comment: Please check my solution as I've just knocked this up quickly without testing. I don't know why yours doesn't work, but simplifying it makes it easier to find out. You can set a debug event at the start of your function and check its being triggered. Note that `.item-1` is a class, not a single element id - did you mean `#item-1`?

Comment: this is not an answer

Comment: I'm just trying to get this to work properly, I don't plan to use those classes/ids. This solution has the same problem as before. Going to debug

Comment: @Igor it may not be an answer, but it is a significant improvement on the original version which makes it easier to spot the problem and is a better implementation. Kevin B has made a comment which probably explains why the problem exists.

Comment: Try adding { queue: false} so the fadeIn doesn't get queued